# Some key note generated event and another key generate event in android not working

Tags: android, events, textview

I am trying to handle event softkeyboard in android 
by this code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnKeyListener  {
     EditText editText1;
     EditText editText2;
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          editText1.setOnKeyListener(this);
          editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          editText2.setOnKeyListener(this);
        //  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)       getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // imm.showSoftInput(editText1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
           }
          public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B|| keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5) 
              {

                  editText2.setText("hello");  
                   return true;
              }


              return false; // pass on to other listeners.
             }
        }
```

but when I press on b or any key never generate any thing

and when I press on the numeric key generated the event

please any one help me and edit on my code.

thanks for helping but i tray that code and not work and yhis the new code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity   {
     EditText editText1;
     EditText editText2;
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

          editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // imm.showSoftInput(editText1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
           }
          public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B|| keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5) 
              {

                  editText2.setText("hello");  
                   return true;
              }


              return false; // pass on to other listeners.

        }

        }
```

please follow my issue
my regards

Answer (score 1):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

*As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version. Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key presses.*

Thus most keys do not generate any KeyEvent.

To capture softkeyboard pressed you can try

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
{ 
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B|| keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5) 
          {

              editText2.setText("hello");  

          }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event); 
}
```

or if you want to process before the softkeyboard processes the key use the same code in dispatchKeyEventPreIme (KeyEvent event)

Comment: thanks but how I can add onKeyEventListener on activety class ??

Comment: please hint me on some line

Comment: thanks for helping but i tray that code and not work and yhis the new 
please follow my issue
my regards

Comment: What happened when you pressed b or 5?

Comment: I edited my answer. So you will not get the key event. Why do you want to capture the keyboard event? there is other way to do it.

Comment: thank you very much for interesting , in fact I try to look from way to write costum message (sms) therfore I need way to handle all key event , please guide me on any thing to do that , my regards

Comment: ok but how I ust that in my code , please edit my code and send it

Comment: same problem , when I press 5 generate event and when I press b not generate  , what difference between numeric key and charecter??
and what I do??

Comment: You have to use TextWatcher to get all the key pressed. I got very complicated. So look up TextWatcher and figure out how to use it for your situation.